# htaccess redirection of pages not working

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, cpanel

I used cPanel to create some redirects for me and the below is what was added to my `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteOptions inherit

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^nextlevelpropertymanagement\.ca$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.nextlevelpropertymanagement\.ca$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/nextlevelpm\.ca\/$1" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cornwallrealty\.ca$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.cornwallrealty\.ca$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/nextlevelpm\.ca\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

If I go to `nextlevelpropertymanagement.ca` or `cornwallrealty.ca` the redirect seems to work; however, if I go to another page on the site such as `cornwallrealty.ca/home/portal/` the redirect does not work. What I would like to happen is:
`cornwallrealty.ca/home/portal/` should redirect to `nextlevelpm.ca/home/portal/`

**UPDATE:**
`/home/.htaccess` has this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /home/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /home/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Do you have any other `.htaccess` files with mod_rewrite directives along the filesystem path? eg. at `/home/.htaccess` or `/home/portal/.htaccess`? (Or any other directives in this `.htaccess` file?)

Comment: @MrWhite See my update to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is the mod_rewrite directives in `/home/.htaccess` are completely overriding the mod_rewrite directives in the parent `.htaccess` file. mod_rewrite directives are not inherited by default.

The format of the current directives can't simply be "inherited", because inherited directives are literally "copied" in place, so the directory prefix naturally changes. In your original directives you are capturing the URL-path (ie. `(.*)`) which is then appended to the *substitution* (ie. `$1` backreference). If you simply inherited these directives, a request for `http://cornwallrealty.ca/home/portal/<something>` would end up being redirected to `http://nextlevelpm.ca/portal/<something>` - the `home` directory is lost, because the URL-path captured by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* would be `portal/<something>`. (This also assumes you are using `InheritBefore` on Apache 2.4+, otherwise it may not get processed correctly at all.)

You can either:

1. Add the following directives to the `/home/.htaccess` file *before* the existing directives.

   ```
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?nextlevelpropertymanagement\.ca [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?cornwallrealty\.ca$
   RewriteRule ^ http://nextlevelpm.ca%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
   ```

   This effectively replicates the directives in the parent `.htaccess` file.

Or,

2. Change the `RewriteRule` directives in the root `.htaccess` file to read:

   ```
   RewriteRule ^ http://nextlevelpm.ca%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
   ```

   And enable mod_rewrite inheritance in the `/home/.htaccess` file, so that the parent directives are executed *before* the child directives, by adding the following directive before the existing WordPress directives (actually, it doesn;t actually matter where you put it, but it is more logical at the top):

   ```
   RewriteOptions InheritBefore
   ```

cPanel uses a lot of unnecessary backslash escaping and generates rather messy mod-rewrite rules.

It's a bit unusual that you have a `RewriteOptions inherit` directive in the root `.htaccess` file - this implies you are inheriting from another parent config? This also prevents you from using `InheritDownBefore` in the parent scope, avoiding you to have to edit the child `.htaccess` file.

The following are only required if you have enabled the automated SSL certs within cPanel:

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
> ```